# How to turn a random price into a random minimal payable cash amount in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I want a math algorithm for javascript

- Input: random from 0.00 to 200.00
- Output: 3 randomly-minimal numbers in banknotes (0.01,0.02,0.05,1,5,10,20,50,100,200)
- (like paying at the shop)

Example input->output:

- 0.15->0.2 or 0.5 or 1
- 4-> 4 or 5 or 10
- 9-> 10 or 15 or 20
- 174 -> 175 or 180 or 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first step, you can multiple `Math.random()` with 200 ([this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_number_between_two_values) will explain more).

Then you can find what banknotes are greater than or equal to the random amount ([Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)).

Then you can use `Math.random()` again to pick 3 random valid banknotes ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array)).

This is the code that does the steps above:

```js
const banknotes = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200]

const handleClick = () => {
  const amountNeeded = Math.random() * 200
  const validBanknotes = banknotes.filter(value => value >= amountNeeded)
  const randomBanknotes = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    randomBanknotes.push(validBanknotes[Math.floor(
      Math.random() * validBanknotes.length)])
  }
  console.log(`Amount needed: ${amountNeeded}. Random banknotes: ${randomBanknotes}`)
}
```

```html
<button onclick='handleClick()'>Click to generate random results</button>
```